# How to parse a specific response of a RESTful WS using JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, android-studio

I am learning how to parse a response from a restful web service It is supposed to retreive a JSON string so I can parse it, I am using the apache libs in android. Following some questions here in StackOverflow I do the following:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try{
            result = httpClient.execute(request, handler); ...
```

with that I can retreive the result of the WS as this:

> "[{\"CodigoRTA\":\"0\",\"MensajeRTA\":\"\",\"Respuesta\":\"[{\\"codigo\\":\\"05\\",\\"nombre\\":\\"ANTIOQUIA\\"},{\\"codigo\\":\\"76\\",\\"nombre\\":\\"VALLE DEL CAUCA\\"}]\"}]"

the thing is that I am trying to parse it with JSONObject and JSONArray without success; When I try to use the JSONObject the errorhandler says that it cannot convert the string into JSONObject, so I look up for an answer or a similar problem and found that if the result starts with [] square brackets  represents starting of an JSONArray node and curly bracket {} represents JSONObject, so I try to use this code:

```
            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                codeDepartment[i] = json_data.getInt("codigo");
                NameDepartment[i] = json_data.getString("nombre");
            }
```

without success either, it now says that "it cannot convert String into JSONArray. So any idea of what can I use? any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: it looks you are getting something different as a response, i mean not a valid JSON, your code looks fine, just try to log the response and make sure it's valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the server response is similar to Json response, the thing is all of the \ that it contains. One thing you could do is to replace or remove 1 of the \ backslash and then try to asign the new value to the JSONArray. Something like this:

```
            result = httpClient.execute(request, handler);                
            result = result.replace("here the info you want to replace", "here with new values to replace with ");
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

hope it help you.

Comment: Ok, I try it with this result = result.replace("\", ""); but when I try to load to the JSONArray it says that that it cannot convert it... :S  don't know what to do....

Comment: I think you would need a regular expression... but I don't have to much knowledge in regular expressions, this link coulb be helpfull
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html